# Riemann integral confusion 2

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

I evaluate the following limit with Riemann integral

$\displaystyle u_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+\frac{k^2-2k+2}{n^2}),\:\
$$\lim _{n\to \infty } u_n=lim _{n\to \infty\ }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+\frac{k^2-2k+2}{n^2})=lim _{n\to \infty\ }\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$=\int _0^1\:f\left(x\right)dx$

I know what it is about but at the final I always have problem because I don't know to get the function... and if I put a function how verify if that is correct? I'm total confused 
Please make me to understand that, I apreciate! For example, I get this function: f:[0,1]-->R, f(x)= ln(1+x), how I verify if that is correct, because if I put k/n instead x we obtain ln(1+k/n) but we have $$log(1+\frac{k^2-2k+2}{n^2})$$ we must have same value?

In general how we find the function ? how we understand which is function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then, using the definition of the integral as the limit of Riemann sums,
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k),
$$
where
$$\frac{k-1}{n}\le x_k\le\frac{k}{n}.$$
Typical choice in applications is $x_k=k/n$. But the choice is arbitrary as long as $x_k\in[(k-1)/n,k/n]$. In your problem $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)$ and
$$
x_k=\frac{\sqrt{k^2-2\,k+2}}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{(k-1)^2+1}}{n},
$$with
$$
\frac{k-1}{n}<\frac{\sqrt{(k-1)^2+1}}{n}<\frac{k}{n}.
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log\Bigl(1+\frac{k^2-2k+2}{n^2}\Bigr)=\int_0^1\log(1+x^2)\,dx.
$$

Comment: Can you give me another exercise like this? to see if I understand...

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2\,k-1}{2\,n}=\int_0^1\sin x\,dx.$$

Comment: $$\frac{k-1}{n}\le x_{_k}=\frac{2k-1}{2n}\le \frac{k}{n}$$ I've right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.